# Resizing didn't affect layout in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am new to **`pyqt5`**  and I am trying to maintain the layout of **`GUI`** even if window_screen is resized with grid layout 
 I tried and searched for this; any guidance in this matter would be appriciated

[image]

code of **`ui-stylying`**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>618</width>
    <height>694</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">
QWidget{background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0.165, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0.0149254 rgba(0, 0, 76, 255), stop:0.373134 rgba(16, 0, 110, 255), stop:0.606965 rgba(0, 49, 122, 255), stop:0.950249 rgba(0, 0, 76, 255));


}

QLineEdit{

background:transparent;
 border:none;
border-bottom:2px solid silver;
color:white;
text-align:center;
}
QLabel{
background:transparent;
 border:none;
border-bottom:2px solid silver;
color:white;
text-align:center;
}
QPushButton {
    border: 2px solid  silver;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color:white;
    min-width: 80px;
}

QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                      stop: 0 #dadbde, stop: 1 #f6f7fa);
}</string>
      </property>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>30</x>
         <y>50</y>
         <width>121</width>
         <height>131</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>TextLabel</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>190</x>
         <y>20</y>
         <width>171</width>
         <height>191</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>TextLabel</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>410</x>
         <y>30</y>
         <width>141</width>
         <height>161</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>TextLabel</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>150</x>
         <y>320</y>
         <width>231</width>
         <height>131</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>TextLabel</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>30</x>
         <y>260</y>
         <width>93</width>
         <height>28</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>PushButton</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>220</x>
         <y>260</y>
         <width>93</width>
         <height>28</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>PushButton</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>410</x>
         <y>250</y>
         <width>93</width>
         <height>28</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>PushButton</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_4">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>230</x>
         <y>490</y>
         <width>93</width>
         <height>28</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>PushButton</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>618</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**`.xml`** file of the **`.ui`**
I want that layout adjust according to resizing of window screen; here I am using **`grid_layout`** 
any help in this case would be appreciated

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: do not believe that transform and transition-* is supported by QSS. Are these properties supported in CSS 2.1?

Comment: @eyllanesc what should I provide to make you understand ?

Comment: The code needed to reproduce the error you have, have you read the link? On the other hand, I already pointed out that the animations you do with CSS are later than CSS 2.1, so Qt does not support them. Here is a complete list https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html

Comment: @eyllanesc ok ok I got it  Thanku and how to make the layout adjustable when I resize window screen

Comment: Have you used QGridLayout? that should do the job, provide the .ui or .py you use

Comment: @eyllanesc check again plz I edit

Comment: again share .ui and/or .py ..........

Comment: Sir I added plz check

Comment: Add the .ui as text since it is an .xml, that is, open it with any editor and copy the .xml in the question

Comment: @eyllanesc check plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using any layout, if you want to establish a QGridLayout you must click somewhere in the blue widget but they do not contain the buttons or labels and press the [image] button generating the following .ui

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>618</width>
    <height>694</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">
QWidget{background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0.165, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0.0149254 rgba(0, 0, 76, 255), stop:0.373134 rgba(16, 0, 110, 255), stop:0.606965 rgba(0, 49, 122, 255), stop:0.950249 rgba(0, 0, 76, 255));


}

QLineEdit{

background:transparent;
 border:none;
border-bottom:2px solid silver;
color:white;
text-align:center;
}
QLabel{
background:transparent;
 border:none;
border-bottom:2px solid silver;
color:white;
text-align:center;
}
QPushButton {
    border: 2px solid  silver;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color:white;
    min-width: 80px;
}

QPushButton:pressed {
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                      stop: 0 #dadbde, stop: 1 #f6f7fa);
}</string>
      </property>
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
       <item row="0" column="0">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>TextLabel</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="1">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>TextLabel</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="2">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>TextLabel</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="0">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>PushButton</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="1">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>PushButton</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="2">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>PushButton</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="1">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>TextLabel</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="3" column="1">
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_4">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>PushButton</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>618</width>
     <height>30</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```